# UWP WebView await navigate

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm trying to get some content on a website which is rendered by JavaScript. So I'm running a `WebView` with `Visibility=Collapsed`. I want to wait unitl `NavigationCompleted` and run some JavaScript then return the value.

The code look like:

```
private async void Foo()
{
    // Want to get value here
    var content = await GetContent();
}

private async Task<string> GetContent()
{
    string content;
    async void handler(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        content = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { script });
        webView.NavigationCompleted -= handler;
    }
    webView.NavigationCompleted += handler;
    webView.Navigate(uri);
    return content;
}
```

Since there is no await in `GetContent()`, the function always returns before `NavigationCompleted` fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `SemaphoreSlim` to asynchronously wait for the `NavigationCompleted` to get raised and handled:

```
private async Task<string> GetContent()
{
    string content;
    using (SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1))
    {
        async void handler(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            content = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { script });
            webView.NavigationCompleted -= handler;
            semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
        webView.NavigationCompleted += handler;
        webView.Navigate(uri);
        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    return content;
}
```

Comment: Is `SemaphoreSlim` better than `TaskCompletionSource` in this scenario?

Comment: @Kiriz: "Better" is subjective but I found it more convenient to use in an `async` method since you can just await its `WaitAsync()` method to block asynchronously without freezing the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).  Create a source, and set its result at the end of the event handler, after you execute the script.  Before you return the content, await the task of the task completion source.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for something, you can use `ManualResetEvent`. Just ensure that you don't use `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne` on the UI thread as it would hang the app.